# Using block in swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures, block

I'm recently started working on swift. Here i'm facing the problem with blocks so please help to do this.

**Class 1:**

I'm using block in Objective-C like this:

```
typedef void (^AHServicesCallsWrapperBlock)(id, NSError *);
```

declaration of block variable:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) AHServicesCallsWrapperBlock webServiceWrapperBlockHandler;
```

and passing block a value

```
self.webServiceWrapperBlockHandler([graphData objectForKey:@"data"], nil);
```

**In Class 2:**
And i'm using this block in another view controller like:

```
AHServiceCallWrapper *webServicesCallsWrapper = [[AHServiceCallWrapper alloc] init];
webServicesCallsWrapper.webServiceWrapperBlockHandler = ^(id response, NSError *error)
{
     // do stuff
}
```

so how can we do this in swift...

Comment: look up closures in swift. there are quite a good amount of tutorials and explanations around. Closures are the equivalent to blocks in swift. https://www.google.com.au/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=clsousure+swift&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=xug6VpO1C-HN8Ae0-oCQAw#q=closure+swift

Comment: how should i do using closures, i search lots of about but not getting properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use closure in Swift, Closures are self-contained blocks of functionality that can be passed around and used in your code. Closures in Swift are similar to blocks in C and Objective-C.

Closure expression syntax has the following general form:

```
{ (parameters) -> return type in
    statements
}
```

**Example :**

If you need to define any closure as object in class like as below,

```
class AHServiceCallWrapper {
  var completionBlock: ((AnyObject, NSError) -> Void)? = nil

  func doSomeStuff() {
    var json = [AnyObject]()
    var error : NSError? = nil
    //Do some stuff if completed
     if let completionBlock = self.completionBlock {
            completionBlock(json, error);
     }
  }
}
```

Now, you can use the implementation like

```
let serviceCall = AHServiceCallWrapper()
serviceCall.completionBlock =  { (response, error) -> Void in
        //Do the stuff on completion 
    }
serviceCall.doSomeStuff()
```